# Meteor router-with-flash package can't be installed

Tags: meteor, meteorite, flash-message

I want to use [router-with-flash](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/router-with-flash) in my Meteor project, but when I run

```
mrt add router-with-flash
```

It causes this error:

```
$ mrt add router-with-flash
✓ router-with-flash
    tag: https://github.com/egtann/meteor-router.git#v0.4.1

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:151
hrow "There was a problem checking out " + self.checkoutType + ": " + (self.co
                                                                    ^
There was a problem checking out tag: v0.4.1
```

In the repository, there is not tag v0.4.1

```
$ git ls-remote --tags git://github.com/egtann/meteor-router.git
c73515515f1d267108f78b4928a6866952290761    refs/tags/v0.1.0
bb806c51efe3686a8da6628269aa67a269a4e076    refs/tags/v0.1.1
2c42dcb1510563071903c90e840dfc546c7a50eb    refs/tags/v0.2.0
7486a639a6793b65e87c11c102e7ecd84813d9f3    refs/tags/v0.2.1
b1e205f3cbde62ae3c91f06429d681580d9aa322    refs/tags/v0.2.2
0a6431923ba2724727233cf9300cdfe81076b9cd    refs/tags/v0.2.3
edd0ad39c66a94536859bd322ea13135afebef0b    refs/tags/v0.2.4
e6718dbccfbbf3f964464053a310ccbcdb766ece    refs/tags/v0.2.5
a1866908a9fb6d287bb877c6583cee93f89e378e    refs/tags/v0.2.6
c328f72a872ee9b8a6707743576b68ff6aa52a13    refs/tags/v0.3.0
ec83354533169fa7b2214f4e1b2faa87164c090f    refs/tags/v0.3.1
bfa1cb328b94278f19fd6cec270f649cbedd5555    refs/tags/v0.3.2
1bb2182407892e9b95f0cf4f15a9a55e0a301c20    refs/tags/v0.3.3
```

What can I do with that?

I used [regular router](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/router) but i need flash messages.

Comment: Seems like the person who committed just forgot to push the new tag.

Answer (score 0):

Check your smart.json-file, and see if the router-with-flash-package is set with the v0.4.1-tag.

Change it to v0.3.3 (or whatever tag you want) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

As Kristoffer says, smart.json should look like this:

```
{
  "packages": {
    "router-with-flash": {
      "git": "https://github.com/egtann/meteor-router.git",
      "tag": "v0.3.3"
    }
  }
}
```

But, "git" repository must be also specified.

**Edit:** but Meteor (v0.6.4) app with package "router-with-flash" version 0.3.3 crashes. I used regular router and implemented flash message with session.